# Where to store sensitive data using cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova

Where can I store sensitive data like session identifiers using Cordova? I have seen that the solutions available are: localStorage, sqlite and IndexedDB. Which solution can I use for storing the data permanently and safely?

Comment: I often make use of local storage in cordova - to store user data and authentication tokens. it is permanent so far as it survives app updates. it is secure in that no other apps can access it. I would imagine sqlite offers the same.

Comment: Try to use localstorage.

Comment: So localstorage for sensitive data and sqlite for other things?

Comment: Generally local storage can be used for limited storages . depends on browser . but sqlite is a database and can be used for storing to large amount of data

Comment: on ios you can use a keychain plugin

Comment: On iOS the localstorage may be deleted by the OS if the system is low on space.